# Find out n numbers of missing elements from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I have an array which carry some integer numbers. Say,`numbers={3,0,1}` or say, `numbers={9,6,4,2,3,5,7,0,1}`. Now I have to find out the missing numbers from the array. As per this example there is only one missing number in each set. 1st one miss 2 and the 2nd one miss 8.

I have already code it. My code not only find out one missing number from specified set it can also find out more than 1 missing numbers from a given set.

**But if two consecutive numbers are missing from same set it fail to find out**.

```
My code
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Missing_number 
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int numbers[]={9,6,4,5,7,0,1};
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        int i=1;

        while ( i < numbers.length ) 
        {
            if ( numbers[i] - numbers[i-1] == 1 ) 
            {
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println( "Missing number is " + ( numbers[i-1] + 1 ) );
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking like that if I am able to append the 1st missing number in the array and then start searching then how's the code look like? `numbers={9,6,4,5,7,0,1}` Now, 8 is already missing from this set. Now I have terminated two more element (2,3) from the list. **Output: as per my code: 2,8** But 3 is also missing but that does not display.

I am thinking like if I am able to append 2 in number array then it may be little bit easier. But as we all know Java array is immutable so we cannot increase it's length.

So, maybe I will use **List**. But in list this type of indexing `number[0]=something`not supported. So how could I proceed then. Am I using list or still stuck into array?

So I take a attempt to create it with an arraylist.

```
Mycode(modified version from array)

 public class T1 {
 public static void main(String args[]){
    List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(9);
    numbers.add(6);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(7);
    numbers.add(0);
    numbers.add(1);
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    int i=1;
    while(i< numbers.size()) {
        if (numbers.get(i) - numbers.get(i-1) == 1) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("Missing number is " + (numbers.get(i-1) + 1));
            numbers.add((numbers.get(i-1)+1));
            Collections.sort(numbers);
        }
        i++;
    }

    }
}
```

Arraylist can solve my problem. But is there any possibility that a simple array can solve this problem?

Comment: But `ArrayList` supports indexing, right?

Comment: With a list, instead of subscripting, you use the `get(int)` method, with the index as the method argument.

Comment: "But as we all know Java array is immutable" - no, Java arrays are mutable. They're not resizable, but they're mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] numbers = { 11, 6, 4, 5, 7, 1 };
Arrays.sort(numbers);
int numbersArrayIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[numbers.length - 1]; i++) {
    if (i == numbers[numbersArrayIndex]) {
        numbersArrayIndex++;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This code uses a `HashSet`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {9, 6, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1};
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = numbers[0]; i < numbers[numbers.length - 1]; i++) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        set.remove(numbers[i]);
    }

    for (int x : set) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}
```

will print:

```
2 3 8
```

Here is how it works:
 1. Adds all numbers from the minimum number of the array to the maximum number of the array  to the set.
 2. Iterates through the array and removes every item of the array from the set.
 3. Prints the remaining items in the set, which are all the missing items of the array.

Comment: how would it handle repeated numbers ?

Comment: @Wesam A HashSet is a data structure that rejects duplicates when added to it. So it stores only unique items.

Answer (score 6):

replace the `else` clause to be:

```
for(int j=numbers[i-1] + 1; j <= numbers[i] - 1; j++) {
    System.out.println( "Missing number is " + ( j ) );
}
```

let's examine the case: {9 ,6 ,4 ,5 ,7 ,0 , 1}
after sorting it will be: {0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
now if `i` is at index 2 it finds the difference between `numbers[i]` and `numbers[i-1]` to be not equal 1 (4 - 1 = 3), now you need ALL the numbers between 1 and 4 which are 2, 3 and thus you must loop from `numbers[i-1]` to `numbers[i]` (exclusive) in order to achieve this.

The complexity of this code is big O of `N` `(O(N))`, where `N` is the biggest element in your array.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of questions which are unanswered here. For Example, *Does an array always start with zero?*, *What is the maximum possible size?* etc.

Here is a simple way to approach this problem,

- Find the maximum number in your set.
- Create an empty `boolean` array of the length as that of the max number you found in the last step plus one.
- Scan your original set and set the value of your new boolean array at the index equal to the number in your original set as `true`.
- Finally scan your `boolean` array to find and pront all the indices with value `false`.

**Example:**

Original Set: {1,0,3}

- **Step 1:** Maximum number in the set = **3**
- **Step 2:** Boolean Array with Length = **3+1** --> {false, false, false, false}
- **Step 3:** While scanning original set and setting values in the `boolean` array this will be the final state --> {true, true, false, true}
- **Step 4:** You'll finally scan the `boolean` array to print **2** since this it is only index which has value = `false`

Comment: My code shown that it is not mandatory to start an array from zero. As the elements depends upon array index. if(numbers[0]=0 ) then its ok if (numbers[0]=5) then it is also ok. All it is matter that the array is a sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MissingElement {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr={10,9,8,7,5,4,3,1,2};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]+1!=arr[i+1])
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i]+1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int[] a= {0,12,14,15,32};
        Arrays.sort(a);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
        {
            if(a[i+1]-a[i]>1)
            {
                int temp=a[i+1]-a[i];
                for(int j=1;j<temp;j++) 
                {
                 System.out.print(a[i]+j + " ");
                }
                temp=0;
            }
        }
```

**Output:** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

Answer (score 0):

```
/*// This will work fine for Normal and duplicate elements
1. Find Largest no and create an array of size Largest+1 
2. Add all numbers from the 1 to till largest in set
3. Iterates through the array and remove every item of the array from the set.
4. Prints the remaining items in the set, which are all the missing items of the array.*/

        int numbers[] = { 3, 1, 5, 5 };

        int Largest = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > Largest) {
                Largest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest no in given array -->" + Largest);
        
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        int arr[] = new int[Largest+1];
        
         for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
         set.add(i);
         }

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            set.remove(numbers[j]);
        }

        System.out.println("Missing  no are :");
        for (int x : set) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: please review the formatting of your answer. This is quite confusing

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printMissingNumbers(int[] arr) {
    int length = arr.length;
    int lastIndesx = arr[length - 1];

    while (length != 0) {
        if (arr[length - 1] == lastIndesx) {
            lastIndesx--;
            length--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("missing number :" + lastIndesx);
            lastIndesx--;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the output for the two examples from the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 5};
        System.out.print("Given number is : ");
        for (int a : arr)
        {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }
        int lengthOfArray = arr.length + 1;
        int sum = lengthOfArray * (lengthOfArray + 1) / 2;
        int sumOfArrayNumber = 0;

        for (int s : arr)
        {
            sumOfArrayNumber = sumOfArrayNumber + s;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("missing number is : " + Integer.valueOf(sum 
        - sumOfArrayNumber));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindingMultipleMissingElements {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int a[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18 };
    int diff = a[0] - 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i]-i != diff)
        {
            while(diff<a[i]-i)
            {
                System.out.println(i + diff);
                diff++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

- In this solution, you use the indices in the Natural Number array to your advantage.
- Initialize the diff variable, which stores the difference of the first index, element 6 in this example, against 0 (first index in the array)
- Why do this? If you traverse an Natural Number Array and subtract the
  element against the index of the said element, it should return the value
  at the first index, consistently. For example:) 6-0=6 at index 0. 7-1=6 at
  index 1. 8-2=6 at index 2. 9-3=6 at index 3. 11-4=5 at index 7. Notice this
  difference.
- Now, we want to traverse through the entire array, calling the for loop.
- We need a condition if statement to check against this difference, and nest a while loop. This while loop will check for the missing elements, with the use of the indexes.
- Once the counter meets the contiguous index, the while loop is terminated.
- Time Complexity: Big O(n)

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this will help you or not, but the same can be done using awk.

> echo "13 2 5 9 4" | xargs | tr " " "\n" | sort -n | awk 'BEGIN { i=1}; {if (i!=$NF) {for(j=i;j<=$NF;j++) {if(j!=$NF) print j; i++}} else i++}'

1
3
6
7
8
10
11
12

Here largest no. in the array is consider as limit of sequence and awk will match each no. with a sequence of integer and if it does not match than it simply print the no.s

Comment: The question has a `java` tag which means answers should be given in Java. With reference to [How should we handle answers in a programming language other than what the OP requested?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271207/5698098) it may be fine (helpful) in some specific cases to give an answer in a different programming language than asked, however doing so in general isn't that helpful. Also when answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them.